# Looking for an alternate history about a US with no developed internet

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The main character is an internet cowboy trying to help people connect to the internet. This USA had rejected development of the WWW and the hero is illicitly setting up internet connections with proscribed tech. Things happen when the forces of law'n'order try to track him down. There's a female reporter and young sidekick as well. Read as part of an a short-story collection in the early 2000s.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

["Unwirer"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?297891) by Cory Doctorow and Charles Stross.  On Doctorow's [blog](https://craphound.com/unwirer/archives/000009.html), there is this spoiler-filled summary

> **An America where the MPAA won its 1995 bid at the NII hearings to
> redesign the Internet. TCP/IP isn't illegal per se, but no funding or
> regulatory support exists for it (and using TCP/IP in the commission
> of even a trivial crime is a serious crime).** Rather, America lives in
> MiniTel Hell, metered, centralized networks that deliver "consumer
> services" instead of end-to-end pipe. By 2000, the leading French IT
> company, Be, which has been largely responsible for the network's
> shift from ASCII to UTF-8, releases the first sub $300 wireless AP.
> WiFi networking becomes an enormous hit in Canada/Mexico, and begins
> to leak across the border, where the unwirers are on a holy mission to
> mesh America into anonymous, unmetered, high-speed network access.
> They're not (just) swapping MP3s, they're SMSing without paying a
> nickel a message, and that's driven the media companies that control
> the net berserk. They field shibboleths that equate the unwirers with
> terrorists and the police clampdown begins in ernest. $PROTAGONIST is
> an unwirer. He works the US-Canada and US-Mex borders with equal
> fluidity. **$SIDEKICK is his seemingly devoted pal, who is in fact a
> provocateur, working to undermine the movement by driving it to
> heights of extremism** -- acts of genuine terrorism. **$MOM is a reporter
> who's working on the story**, tagging along on condition of $PROT and
> $SIDE's anonymity. She's playing dumber than she really is, to draw
> them out, but she's really quite sympathetic and even has a modest AP
> in her home in DC (many people do now, especially adhesive wireless
> repeaters that can be frisbeed up against buildings to make local
> anonymous meshnets). $MOM is about the blow the lid off the Feds'
> heavy-handedness (and the fact that they're getting their marching
> orders from media companies, something she can finally document), when
> she twigs to $SIDE's provo role. She outs him, there is a chase scene,
> guns are fired, hilarity ensues.

Comment: That sounds like...a story that was written by Cory Doctorow, all right.

Comment: It is the Cory Doctorowiest story that ever Cory Doctorowed

Comment: sad thing is (like many Cory Doctorow stories) it's a very plausible alternate history

Comment: Thanks! That's the one!

Comment: Great! You can click the check mark to accept if you'd like